# Is there a way to get the date of the first boot of an old mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to read the date when a mac first booted via terminal or system information GUI?
Maybe there's a file set at this moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest answer to my problem could be:

`ls -lt /private/var/db/ | tail -3`

which shows for example:

```
drwx------ 8 root wheel 272 Apr 18 2009 krb5kdc
drwx------ 3 root wheel 102 Apr 18 2009 dhcpclient
-r-------- 1 root wheel 48 Jan 14 2009 SystemKey
```

Ignoring the date of the "SystemKey"-file.

Comment: Why do you ignore the data of System key and trust the other dates?

Comment: In my case `Systemkey` is older than the manufacturing date of the computer. And the timestamp of the other files match the date I've upgrade to El Capitan. Hmm.

Comment: In my case, the two files other than SystemKey are volinfo.database and dhcpclient. I checked my bank statements and their dates match the date on my purchase receipt from the Apple Store. So, this was perfectly accurate for me despite a few OS upgrades!

Answer (score 4):

The file `/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` is created on the first boot. I'd bet it doesn't get migrated over from an old mac if you choose that, so it might be a good place to start your search for a file stamp.

Any file can be changed later, but you have to go looking for this one.

AppleCare can also provide you details if you give them your serial number. They have manufacture date, sale date (sometimes inaccurate) and possibly if the user runs the "Mac Buddy" setup assistant and registers the Mac online during the first boot.

Comment: I've updated from Leopard -> Snow Leopard -> Lion in my case. A `ls -hla` of `/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` shows the date of the last OS update. There are other files in the folder which show the possible answer but I'm not sure which to trust. There's even a file with a date before the manufacturing period :O

Comment: Bummer - that was the best place I could think of. I suppose I would fire up a `find` command on a mac I already knew the first service date and find some files around then - and work backwards to see if it was reliable on other macs with unknown birthdays.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you for your answer. I think a `ls -lt | tail -10` which shows 
`drwx------    8 root      wheel         272 Apr 18  2009 krb5kdc
drwx------    3 root      wheel         102 Apr 18  2009 dhcpclient
-r--------    1 root      wheel          48 Jan 14  2009 SystemKey`
 is pretty reliable except the "SystemKey" file.

Comment: Dali - feel free to make another answer with the real file that worked for you or editing my answer to make it better! Comments are great, but can get hidden later down the line. I'm glad something there worked for your query.

Answer (score 1):

I figured, I can get the date from System Information (Profiler) in all places. I had the habit of customizing the app the moment I have new machine. So it was a great found.

[image: System Information]

**P.S**: I'm saying good bye (wipe & install) to this work machine today, 1967 days of self learning of this instance going to disappear :-(

Comment: Bear in mind that if the disk has been wiped, none of these methods will show the original date.