# Gathering information through Terminal commands

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

Is there a way through bash/terminal commands to get the following -

- Manufactured date
- OS install date
- Anti Virus installed

I have been doing some research and these three items seem to not exist just wondering if anyone has any ideas.

PS: If anyone is interested its is for an Audit program I am writing that requires these commands.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to check when Macbook was turned on first time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215947/how-to-check-when-macbook-was-turned-on-first-time/215971) for details about the OS install date.

As for anti virus software, there are several products out there. One way to check for installation is to check whether the corresponding application is installed in `/Applications`.

Comment: Thanks patrix using stat -x /var/db/.AppleSetupDone might be what I need for OS install. Now to find the other two! cheers